# PowerShell How do I copy a fle with today's date

Tags: powershell, file, date

I want to copy a file and add today's date to its name. I thought it would work like this:

```
$DATE = Get-Date
    
Copy-Item -Path $HOME\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\wordbook\standard.dic -Destination $HOME\Desktop\standard_$DATE.dic
```

However, it doesn't. How can it be done?

Comment: "it doesn't" is not a good error statement. What, exactly, happens? If there's an error message, paste that as text [edit] to the question body. (I guess you are getting an error about syntax, since default date format contains spaces. But, don't make us guess!)

Comment: You need to be clearer on how you want the date to appear.  e.g. `standard_ddMMyyyy.dic`, `standard_MMddyyyy.dic`, `standard_yyyyMMdd.dic`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$DATE = Get-Date -UFormat "%m-%d-%Y"
$outname = "standard" + "_" + $DATE
Copy-Item -Path C:\Temp\Test\Testfile.dic -Destination C:\Temp\Test\$outname.dic
```

Output:

```
 standard_10-04-2021.dic
```